# Programmatically get docker manifest

Tags: docker, aws-sdk

I’m using the aws-sdk for nodejs for pushing a docker image to the aws ecr using this call: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_PutImage.html#API_PutImage_RequestSyntax

In code the sdk asks for the docker manifest which I don’t understand. I don’t have a way to get the manifest through dockerode (the npm package I use for talking to the docker api) and the ‘docker manifest’ cli command seems to be epirimental. How do I get the manifest, which is a json document described here:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-1/

Answer (score 0):

I might be on the wrong track. It says in the documentation:

> This operation is used by the Amazon ECR proxy, and it is not intended
>   for general use by customers for pulling and pushing images. In most
>   cases, you should use the docker CLI to pull, tag, and push images.

So I may not be able to use this as I intended